# .net COMVisible/ComInterop - can you use a type without registering it?

Tags: com, regasm, comvisible

My first attempts at this have failed but I'm hoping it is possible. If I have a class like this that is COM registered:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface Resolver
{
    object Resolve(string type);
}

[ProgId("ClassResolver")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("53DB4409-0827-471D-94CE-2601D691D04C")]
public class Class1:Resolver
{
    public object Resolve(string type)
    {
        return (ClassLibrary2.Interface1) new ClassLibrary2.Class1();
    }
}
```

Can I use it to return Class2.Interface1 which is ComVisible but not registered (it's in a different library):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface Interface1
{
    string SomeMethod();
}


public class Class1:Interface1
{
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SomeMethod");
        return "SomeMethod";
    }
}
```

My first attempts have returned the error: IUnknown:SomeMethod (No exported method), but I'm hoping there might be some trick to doing this that I don't know.

Comment: The error message does not look good, something is wrong with the client code.  Returning *object* from a method requires the client to use "late binding" through IDispatch or a QueryInterface call on the variant for the expected interface type.  It can never be IUnknown.  I'd guess at an unwise attempt at casting, possibly induced by having two distinct type libraries.  Just a guess, clearly it needs to be explicitly documented in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is possible if you mark the class as ComVisible (just the interface as ComVisible wasn't enough). I can now use ClassLibrary3 via COM. See below code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface Resolver
{
    object Resolve(string type);
}

[ProgId("ClassResolver2")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("83720331-12CB-48E1-947C-2413F7B9AB89")]
public class Class1:Resolver
{
    public object Resolve(string type)
    {
        return new ClassLibrary3.Class1();
    }
}
}
```

Totally separate library that was not "Regasm"ed:

```
namespace ClassLibrary3
{

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class1 
{
    public string SomeMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ClassLibrary3.Class1.SomeMethod....");
        return "ClassLibrary3.Class1.SomeMethod";
    }
}
}
```